# Why do Java people frequently consume exceptions silently?

Tags: java, exception

I never did any serious Java coding before, but I learned the syntax, libraries, and concepts based on my existing skills (Delphi & C#).  One thing I hardly understand is that I've seen so much code that silently consume exceptions after `printStackTrace` like this:

```
    public void process() {
        try {
            System.out.println("test");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

There is similar code like this one in almost every Java article & project I ran into. Based on my knowledge this is very bad. The exception should almost always be forwarded to the outer context like this:

```
    public void process() {
        try {
            System.out.println("test");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
```

Most of the time the exception should end up being handled at the outermost loop which belongs to the underlying framework (Java Swing for example). Why does it look like the norm to code like this in the Java world? I'm puzzled.

Based on my background, I'd prefer to remove printStackTrace *entirely*. I would simply rethrow as an unhandled aka `RuntimeException` (or, even better, `AssertionError`), then catch and log it at the most appropriate place: the framework outermost loop.

```
    public void process() {
        try {
            System.out.println("test");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd say that it is not really silently when the stack trace is printed :)

Comment: May I quote Isaac Waller "But your program does not quit and keeps on going, most probably in undefined state"

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood, Your comment got so many votes and that even more puzzle me about typical java mindset.

Comment: better doing at least a printStackTrace() instead of havind an empty catch...

Comment: I think that a stack trace gives you enough information to spot the bug quick and easily: the error message, the problematic line (including line number) and the "trace" the program ran. You can then inspect logs with a very clear idea about what you are looking for.

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood - it's silent from the caller's perspective. The caller has no idea that anything happened. Now if that's what's intended, that's fine, but in general, that's bad news. Also - think about what happens in an applet - the user will never see the output (unless they happen to have the java console open, which is never). Ok, so noone uses applets any more ;) Similar for servletm though - end user doesn't know anything happened - it just gets stashed in a log.

Comment: I plead guilty, your honour. (Though it's in a codebase that uses this, uh, pattern thousands of times already.)

Comment: Exception throwing in Java is soo prevalent that most Java coders ignore them because if you do the correct error catching then you will need to write a lot more code... so basically all those java programmers do this because they are slothful.

Comment: When I don't care about exceptions, I put the method body inside a try block and throw a AssertionError with a String explaining why and/or where that error was generated

Comment: Only swallow exceptions at the spot where recovery actually happens.

Comment: Why do they do that?  Because they don't know what they're doing.

Comment: Just find out that the true answer to this question is that -- this is exactly how it's suppose to be done in Java by design. For sake of "robustness"
https://twitter.com/klavereelco/status/1580486492824010752

Answer (score 210, accepted):

I have always thought, that's similar to the following scenario:

> *"A man gets shot.*
>
> *He holds his breath and has enough strength to take a bus.*
>
> *10 miles later the man gets off of the bus, walks a couple of blocks and dies."*

When the police gets to the body, they don't have a clue of what has just happened. They may have eventually but it is much harder.

Better is:

> *"A man gets shot and he dies instantly, and the body lies exactly where the murder just happened."*

When the police arrives, all the evidence is in place.

If a system is to fail, better is to [fail fast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast)

Addressing the question:

1. Ignorance.

     +
2. Sloth

**EDIT:**

Of course, the catch section is useful.

If something can be done with the exception, that's where it should be done.

Probably that is NOT an exception for the given code, probably it is something that is expected ( and in my analogy is like a bulletproof jacket, and the man was waiting for the shot in first place ).

And yes, the catch could be used to [Throw exceptions appropriate to the abstraction](http://www.google.com/search?q=Effective+Java+Throw+exceptions+appropriate+to+the+abstraction)

Comment: Swallowing exceptions isn't failing, never mind failing fast. On the other hand if your method contract has a parameter which is a string of digits, and you're parsing it into an Integer, you can swallow the ParseException. If you're writing a specific functionality, define a custom exception for that functionality failing, then catch  exceptions and throw your custom exception (with the original exception as an argument). It can then fail fast to somewhere where meaningful behaviour can occur (display to user, send email, just log, quit this server thread, etc).

Comment: Wait a minute... I need to stop laughing first... Okay...
That was by far the most entertaining answer to a question I have seen so far.  It very much gets the point across.  Though it may be very helpful to pass the exception "up the chain" for handling, it is better to at least catch the exception first and then pass it so some useful information could be included.

Comment: The exception isn't the error.  Throwing an exception is the man getting shot, and then detailing the incident in a note and attaching it to a carrier pigeon who's trained to fly to the nearest homicide squad.

Comment: @Oscar, +100 if I could. Poor exception handling is the result of IGNORANCE and MALICE, not laziness. Laziness = as little effort as possible. Stupidity in handling exceptions causes more work, not reduces it... of course, it usually causes more work for somebody else, which is why it seems "lazy".

Comment: I see your point oscar, but all handling the exception or logging it does is show you that the exception happened.  If you throw it all the way back up the chain, it lets you know which method ultimately invoked the exception.

Answer (score 33):

Usually that is due to the IDE offering a helpful 'quick fix' that wraps the offending code in a try-catch block with that exception handling. The idea is that you actually DO something, but lazy developers don't.

This is bad form, no doubt.

Comment: Agreed, the example given looks like Eclipse's default quick-fix, with the // FIXME: comment removed.

Comment: Well, you said "This is bad form, *no doubt*" and I 100% agree. However, some other answers and comments make me very curious in the philosophy behind that very large portion (I believe) of java developers.

Comment: I really wish Eclipse would do something drastic there. Like, e.printStackTrace(); System.exit(1);

Comment: I have changed my IDE settings to generate a catch body that rethrows it as RuntimeException. That's a much better default.

Comment: If I'm sure that the exception should never happen, I usually throw an AssertionError instead of RuntimeException as a way to document my intention.

Comment: @Esko Luontola: I'm not aware of the AssertionError before. And yes this is a much better option in my opinion. But again, wonder why it's not a well known practice.

Comment: great point, however knowing eclipse people i cant imagine that anybody can make them change the default. however if you feel strong about it you should submit bug/feature to eclipse bug-tracker(however it might turn into RuntimeException flame-war).

Answer (score 22):

This is a classic [straw man argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man).  `printStackTrace()` is a debugging aid.  If you saw it on a blog or in a magazine it was because the writer was more interested in illustrating a point *other* than exception handling.  If you saw it in production code, the developer of that code was ignorant or lazy, nothing more.  It shouldn't be held up as an example of common practice in the "java world".

Comment: so its ok for pro-programmer to write bad code in blog or magazine and not in production? id rather write bad code in production. if really smart guy is using printStackTrace he convinces people to use it. i understand that exception code is 8 chars longer, but ...

Comment: @ABCDE: I totally disagree.  You'd rather write bad code in production?  That's code that's supposed to work!  Blog and magazine articles are supposed to illustrate a point.  If error handling isn't the point, then it can be just clutter.  A lot of writers use greatly simplified error handling or none at all in articles.  This isn't an example to be followed.

Answer (score 19):

1. Java forces you to handle all Exceptions explicitly.  If a method that your code calls is declared to throw FooException and BarException your code **MUST** handle (or throw) those exceptions.  The only exception to this is *RuntimeException*, which is silent like a ninja.
2. Lots of programmers are lazy (myself included), and it's very easy to just print the stack trace.

Comment: But your program does not quit and keeps on going, most probably in undefined state.

Comment: How is the state undefined if you know the type of exception? That's a cute little quote, but usually the program CAN and HAS TO keep on going. You don't want the whole application to crash for an exception - tell the user and ask them to do whatever it was again.

Comment: The application won't crash if the exception is properly handled at the outest level.

Comment: At least half the exceptions are "RuntimeExceptions" you make it sound like there is just one.  And it's not silent, and uncaught RutimeException will print a stack trace and crash your program.

Comment: @greenieMeanie Generally at development you want it to crash hard with the slightest problem--don't let developers get away with screwing up a call--don't be forgiving about ANYTHING.  On the other hand, when you ship it, you want to go for the opposite.  Log every exception invisibly and try your best to recover and continue (which Java is really quite good at).

Comment: @AgileJon I am extraordinarily lazy; e.printStackTrace() causes me way more work than it saves so that is something I *never* do intentionally. Procrastinater != Lazy, though they are often confused.

Comment: If you're lazy, change your code template in Eclipse/whatever to be something like catch (Exception e) { log.debug("Caught an exception", e); } OK, not a 100% clean solution but it's still better than nothing, right?

Comment: @AligeJon: RuntimeExceptions, which are silent like .NET exceptions

Comment: Not all exceptions, just the checked ones.

Answer (score 12):

because **Checked Exceptions** is a failed experiment

(maybe printStackTrace() is **the real problem**? :)

Comment: Why RuntimeException is not the choice ?

Comment: A great deal of the java standard libraries use checked exceptions, thus you wind up having to deal with them frequently

Comment: Yeah, because we really want people writing hand-rolled JDBC (which usually when written itself instead of using a framework is ALREADY bad enough) to not be aware and FORCED to catch all the possible SQLExceptions that may occur.... /s

Comment: They aren't a failed experiment. Actually, i like them! As pointed out by other answers programmers tend to be lazy and just ignore error cases. Since checked exceptions force you to deal with them you will have better code overall. (If the Programmer is not ignoring them silently). Also, even you aren't lazy, you cannot forget to cath an important exception because the compiler will tell you to do so...

Comment: checked exceptions is a failure for several reasons: check some of them http://www.mindview.net/Etc/Discussions/CheckedExceptions

Comment: +1 couldn't agree more. Checked exceptions often make code *less* safe and this is one example of how.

Comment: @dfa, I would be inclined to agree if other languages had a mechanism to enforce the proper documenting of what exceptions can be thrown by a method. Too often, I'm forced to catch "exception" and hope I don't unintentionally catch an exception I shouldn't handle. We need some middle ground that forces better documentation or allows for IDE-analysis to see what exceptions can be thrown.

Comment: checked exception are only a failure if you have developers who don't know how to handle them and ignore them. However reading the code this becomes obvious that exception have been ignored. With unchecked exceptions this is not obvious.

Comment: @cletus: Stupid programmers and stupid APIs often make code less safe, not checked exceptions

Comment: Checked exceptions definitely aren't perfect, but they do force you to face the reality that sometimes, things don't go according to plan. Non-checked exceptions are just trying to pretend that we live in a perfect world where nothing goes wrong

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: checked exceptions are a failure because very smart people like the ones who came with the amazing Swing framework puke on them and refuse to use them.  And I very much doubt that people like Joshua Bloch or the ones behind the Spring framework "don't know how to correctly use them".  Sure, you *can* correctly deal with a checked exception.  The real brokenness is that someone, somewhere, thought that throwing one was an acceptable practice.

Comment: I find it amazing that throwing unchecked exceptions is acceptable practice.  There are many functions even in the JRE which throw undocument unchecked exceptions. Are you really suggesting that unchecked exception are better in any way. Certainly not for producing quality code.

Comment: The problem with checked exceptions is that Java makes "checked" versus "unchecked" a property of an exception *type*, rather than a property of throw sites, catch sites, and exception instances.  It would be very helpful if there existed "throw checked", "catch checked", and "rethrow checked" statments, and an easy means of directing that a checked exception which wasn't caught should percolate up the stack as an unchecked exception.  There is a huge difference semantically between method throwing an exception for the reason documented in its API, versus a method calling a method which...

Comment: ...unexpectedly throws that same type of exception.  It would be helpful if one could say `catch checked InvalidOperationException` and know that it would only catch such an exception which occurred for the "expected" reason.  Unfortunately, Java makes such things very awkward; .net, which doesn't have checked exceptions, really does no better.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Throwing undocumented unchecked exceptions is a documentation failure, but I wonder if there's really a case when you could handle the exception in a way different from what you did before you discovered the problem? I hate checked exceptions, but a concrete example might help.

Answer (score 12):

I find there are often 2 reasons this is done

1. Programmer was lazy
2. Programmer wanted to guard an entry point into there component (correctly or incorrectly)

I do not believe this is a phenomenon limited to Java.  I've seen such coding often in C# and VB.Net as well.

On the surface it's quite shocking and looks terrible.  But really it's nothing new.  It occurs all the time in C++ applications which use error code return values vs. exceptions.  The difference though is that ignoring a potentially fatal return value doesn't really look any different than calling a function that returns void.

```
Foo* pFoo = ...;
pFoo->SomeMethod(); // Void or swallowing errors, who knows?
```

This code looks better but if SomeMethod() were to say return an HResult, it would be semantically no different than swallowing an exception.

Comment: I think Reason 1 far more common than Reason 2 for this question in particular

Comment: @matt b, agreed.  Laziness is responsible for a good portion of the bugs I fix these days.

Comment: ignoring an error code is a damn sight quicker, and uses a lot less boilerplate code!

Answer (score 6):

I have to say I slightly resent the tone that implies this sort of lax error-handling behaviour is something fundamental to Java programmers. Sure, Java programmers can be lazy, just like every other programmer, and Java's a popular language, so you'll probably see a lot of code swallowing exceptions.

Also, as has been pointed out elsewhere, there are understandable frustrations with Java's enforced declaration of checked exceptions, although personally I don't have a problem with that.

What I have a problem with, I guess, is that you're breezing through a bunch of articles and code snippets on the web without bothering to consider the context. The truth is, when you're writing a technical article trying to explain how some particular API works, or how to get started with something, then you're very likely to skip over some aspects of the code - the error handling that's not directly related to what you're demonstrating is a likely candidate for disposal, especially if the exception is unlikely to occur in the example scenario.

People who write articles of that nature have to maintain a reasonable signal-to-noise ratio, and rather fairly, I think, that means they have to assume you know some basics about the language you're developing in; how to deal properly with errors, and a bunch of other things. If you come across an article and notice a lack of proper error checking, then that's fine; just make sure that when you incorporate those ideas (but of course, never the exact code itself, right?) into your production code, you'll deal with all those bits and bobs that the author sensibly left out, in a manner that's most suited to what you're developing.

I do have a problem with very high-level introductory articles that breeze over such issues without ever returning to them, but please be aware that there's not some particular "mindset" of Java programmers regarding error handling; I know of plenty of your beloved C# programmers who don't bother dealing with all their problems, either.

Comment: But writing a high-level article using `try {...} catch (IOException e) {}` is plain stupid (and a TODO does NOT help). It will surely mislead many beginners to doing the same. Moreover, it's *much more to write* than `throws IOException`, which is correct most of the time. Maybe once per paper, it's not possible and then writing `throw wrap(e)` (without boring to define `wrap`) is a good solution. *One of the first things I leaned in Java, is that silently swallowing is terrible thing and I take great care so I don't do it even temporarily (even crashing is way better in the long run).*

Answer (score 5):

A System.out print or e.printStackTrace() - which implies use of System.out is usually a red flag meaning someone didn't bother to do a diligent job. Excepting desktop Java Applications, most Java apps are better off using logging.

If the failure mode for a method is a no-operation, it's perfectly fine to eat an exception, whether you record the reason (and existence) or not. More typically, however, the catch clause should be taking some sort of exceptional action.

Rethrowing an exception is something that's best done when you either use the catch to clean up part of the work at a level where the necessary information is still available or when you need to transform the exception to an exception type more amenable to the caller.

Answer (score 3):

It is only consumed silently if the catch block is empty really.

As far as articles goes they are probably more interesting in proving some other point besides how to deal with exceptions. They just want to get straight to the point and have the shortest possible code.

Obviously you are right though, exceptions should at least be logged if they are going to be 'ignored'.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, the reason you see this is for one of three reasons:

1. An IDE generated the try-catch block

   - The code was copied and pasted
   - The developer put the stacktrace in to debug but never came back to handle the exception properly

The last point is the least likely to occur.  I say this because I don't think anyone really debugs this way.  Stepping through code with a debugger is a much easier way to debug.

The best description of what *should* be done in a catch block can be found in Chapter 9 of [*Effective Java* by Joshua Bloch](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780137150021).

Answer (score 2):

In C# all exceptions are runtime exceptions, but in Java you have runtime exceptions and checked exceptions, that you have to either catch, or declare in your methods. If you call any method that has a "throws" at the end, you have to either catch the exceptions mentioned there, or your method has to also declare those exceptions.

Java Articles usually just print the stack trace or have a comment because the exception handling is irrelevant to the article's subject matter. In projects though, something should be done about it, depending on the type of exception.

Answer (score 2):

You should see this very often if the programmer does his job right. Ignoring Exception is a bad, bad practice! But there are some reasons why some might do this and the more apporiate solutions:

- "This wont happen!"
  Sure, sometime you "know" that this Exception won't happen, but its still more appropiate to rethrow a runtime exception whith the occoured Exception as "cause" instead of just ignoring it. I bet it will occour sometime in the future. ;-)
- Prototyping Code
  If you're just typing your stuff down to see if it works out you might want to ignore all Exceptions that might occour. This is the only case i do some lazy catch(Throwable). But if the code will turn out into something useful, i include proper exception handling.
- "I dont know what to do!"
  I saw much code, especially library code, which swallows occouring exceptions because in this layer of the application no proper handling can be done. DONT DO THIS! Just rethrow the exception (either by adding a throws clause in the method signature or wrapping the exception into a library specific one).

Comment: Seeing catch(Throwable) made me cringe.

Comment: Absolutly. I just use either catch(Throwable) or throws Throwable in code if im playing around. "Real" code must not include it! period.

Comment: Agreed.  I cringe because I've seen it before.  If one other developer sees that you've written catch(Throwable), it's gone too far!  :)

Comment: You kind of want to catch(Throwable) at the top-most level, even if the code shuts down the process. Attempting to hobble along with one thread missing, might not be the best idea.

Answer (score 2):

You should always forward it on or handle it suitably in a real-world context. A lot of articles and tutorials will simplify their code to get the more important points across though and one of the easiest things to simplify is error-handling (unless what you are doing is writing an article on error-handling that is :)). As java code will check for exception handling then putting a simple silent (or logging statement) catch block on is the simplest method to provide a working example.

If you find this in anything other than example code, feel free to forward the code onto TDWTF, although they may have too many examples of it by now :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that most of java programmers do not know what to do with Exceptions, and quite always consider it as an annoyance that slows their coding of the "nominal" case.
Of course they're totally wrong, but it's difficult to convince them that IT IS important to correctly deal with exceptions.
Every time I encounter such a programmer (it happens frequently) I give him two reading entries :

- the famous Thinking In java
- A short and interesting article of Barry Ruzek available here : www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/dev2arch/2006/11/effective-exceptions.html

By the way, I strongly agree that it is stupid to catch a typed exception to rethrow it embedded in a RuntimeException :

- if you catch it, HANDLE it.
- otherwise, change your method signature to add possible exceptions that you would / could not handle, so your caller would have a chance to do it on his own.

Comment: I 100% would not trust Bruce Eckel on this issue :)

Answer (score 2):

The combination of checked exceptions and interfaces lead to the situation that the code must handle exections that never ever get thrown. (The same applies to normal inheritance, too, but it's more common and easier to explain with interfaces)

Reason: The implementation of an interface may not throw (checked) exceptions other than those defined in the interface specification. For that reason, the creators of an interface, not knowing which methods of a class implementing the interface might actually need to throw an exception, might specifiy that all methods might throw at least one type of exception. Example: JDBC, where everything and its grandma is declared to throw SQLException.

But in reality, many methods of real implementations simply cannot fail, so under no circumstances, they ever throw an exception. Code calling this methods must still somehow "handle" the exception, and the easiest way is to do that swallow the exception. Nobody wants to clutter his code with seemingly useless error-handling that never ever gets executed.

Comment: IMHO, there should be a language shorthand to catch and rethrow such exceptions as runtime errors.  Notating such shorthand would make clear both in code and behavior that such exceptions should be regarded as representing "unexpected" conditions.  Swallowing is bad, since if an exception does get thrown, *something is seriously wrong* and calling code should find out about it.

Comment: supercat: I like that idea, but it might cancel out the (IMO questionable) benefit of checked exceptions.

Comment: It would be better if checkedness was a characteristic of catch/throw sites and exception instances rather than exception classes, so that checked exceptions could propagate as unchecked exceptions of the same class, but even wrap-and-rethrow would be a major improvement on the status quo, and it could easily be added as a new feature.  It would be especially useful in cases where a method which might throw a checked exception on its own calls other methods which are declared as throwing that same exception *but aren't expected to ever actually do so*.  If one of the latter methods throws...

Comment: ...a caller that is expecting to handle the exception thrown from the outer method shouldn't catch one thrown by the inner methods, since it wouldn't represent the condition the caller was expecting.  Were I designing a runtime framework from scratch, I'd use a different mechanism for checked and unchecked exceptions, such that checked exceptions would add slight overhead to a successful function call but have much less overhead when thrown than would unchecked exceptions (among other things, a caught-as-checked exception wouldn't have a stack trace).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, calling printStackTrace() isn't really silent handling.

The reason for this sort of "swallowing" of the exception is that, if you keep passing the exception up the chain, you still have to handle the exception **somewhere** or let the application crash. So, handling it at the level it occurs with an information dump is no worse than handling it at the top level with an information dump.

Answer (score 1):

Its lazy practice - nothing short of it really.

Its usually done when you really don't care about the exception - rather than increasing your finger-work.

Answer (score 1):

You would usually swallow an exception when you cannot recover from it but it is not critical. One good example is the IOExcetion that can be thrown when closing a database connection. Do you really want to crash if this happens? That's why Jakarta's DBUtils have closeSilently methods.

Now for checked exception that you cannot recover but are critical (usually due to programming errors), don't swallow them. I think exceptions should be logged the nearest as possible to the source of the problem so I would not recommend removing the printStackTrace() call. You will want to turn them into RuntimeException for the sole purpose of not having to declare these exceptions in you business method. Really it doesn't make sense to have high level business methods such as createClientAccount() throws ProgrammingErrorException (read SQLException), there is nothing you can do if you have typos in your sql or accessing bad indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree that rethrowing a checked exception is a better idea.  Catching means handling; if you have to rethrow, you shouldn't catch.  I'd add the throws clause to the method signature in that case.

I would say that wrapping a checked exception in an unchecked one (e.g., the way Spring wraps the checked SQLException into an instance of its unchecked hierarchy) is acceptable.

Logging can be considered handling.  If the example was changed to log the stack trace using log4j instead of writing to the console, would that make it acceptable?  Not much of a change, IMO.

The real issue is what is considered exceptional and an acceptable recovery procedure.  If you can't recover from the exception, the best you can do is report the failure.

Answer (score 1):

The real point of exceptions is to simplify error handling and separate it from error detection.  This is in contrary to representing errors by error codes, where error
handling code is scattered everywhere and every call which may fail shall be checked
for return code.

If exception represents an error (which is most of the cases) usually the most reasonable way to handle it is to bail out and leave the handling to some upper layer.
Rethrowing different exception should be considered if some meaningful semantics is added to it i.e., this error is an unusual system failure / temporary (networking) problem / this is client or server side error etc.

Of all error handling strategies the most ignorant is hiding or simply printing error message and going forward as nothing happened.

---

Sun folks wanted the code to be more explicit and forced programmers to write which exceptions may be thrown by which method.  It seemed to be right move -- anybody will
known what to expect in return from any method call given it's prototype (it may return
value of this type or throw an instance of one of the specified classes (or it's subclass)).

But as it turned out with lots of ignorant Java programmers they now treat exception handling as if it was a language bug/"feature" which needed a workaround and write code in worst or almost worst possible way:

- The error is handled right away in context not suitable to decide what to do with it.
- It is displayed or ignored silently and computing continues even when further code has
  no chance to run properly.
- The caller of method can not differentiate whether it finished successfully or not.

---

How to write the "right way" than?

- Indicate every base class of exceptions which can be thrown in method header.
  AFAICR Eclipse can do it automatically.
- Make the throw list in method prototype meaningful.
  Long lists are pointless and "throw Exception" is lazy (but useful when you not bother
  much about exceptions).
- When writing the "wrong way" simple "throw Exception" is much better and takes
  less bytes than "try{ ... } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }".
- Rethrow chained exception if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't ever, ever, ever wrap a checked exception in an unchecked exception.

If you find yourself dealing with exceptions that you don't think you should then my advice is that you are probably working at the wrong level of abstraction.

I'll elaborate: checked and unchecked exceptions are two very different beasts. Checked exceptions are similar to the old method of returning error codes... yes, they are somewhat more painful to handle than error codes but they have advantages too. Unchecked exceptions are programming errors and critical system failures... exceptional exceptions in other words. When trying to explain what an exception is a lot of people get into a complete mess because they don't acknowledge the difference in these two, very different, cases.

Comment: Wrapping in AssertionError is resonable for me. AssertionError is the abstraction that apply anywhere, IMO.

Comment: I'll elaborate: checked and unchecked exceptions are two very different beasts. Checked exceptions are similar to the old method of returning error codes... yes, they are somewhat more painful to handle than error codes but they have advantages too. Unchecked exceptions are programming errors and critical system failures... exceptional exceptions in other words. When trying to explain what an exception is a lot of people get into a complete mess because they don't acknowledge the difference in these two, very different, cases.

Comment: Probably I'm among the people getting into a complete mess, as you put it. However, my real point is that why allow the execution to continue while you have choice to interrupt it. (with either AssertionError or, if you prefer, change your interface to include extra Exception.

Comment: Couldn't disagree with the primary assertion of this answer more. The elaboration has merits.

Comment: @CurtainDog: Checked exceptions are for "expected" problems.  If method x throws (checked) FooException in some cases, and method y, which calls x, does not expect such cases to arise, then if such cases *do* arise, they represent an *unexpected* problem; even if there happens to be something further up the call stack which is expecting a `FooException`, the present situation will not match what that upstream caller would expect when a `FooException` is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Because they haven't learned this trick yet:

```
class ExceptionUtils {
    public static RuntimeException cloak(Throwable t) {
        return ExceptionUtils.<RuntimeException>castAndRethrow(t);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static <X extends Throwable> X castAndRethrow(Throwable t) throws X {
        throw (X) t;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) { // Note no "throws" declaration
        try {
            // Do stuff that can throw IOException
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Pretend to throw RuntimeException, but really rethrowing the IOException
            throw ExceptionUtils.cloak(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is nice trick, but personally I would prefer to throw a more specific exception with a cause something like 'throw new ServiceUnavailableException(ex)'

Comment: rethrow method of Apache's ExceptionUtils does exactly this. It's a good trick. https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/ExceptionUtils.java

Answer (score 0):

If you want your exception to be handled outside the scope of the current method you don't need to to catch it actually, instead you add 'throws' statement to the method signature.

The try/catch statements that you've seen are only in the code where programmer explicitly decided to handle the exception in place and therefore not to throw it further.

Comment: Not true - if you're implementing an interface method, or overriding a superclass method, that has no 'throws' declaration, then you can't just add one.  In those cases you either have to wrap the exception in a RuntimeException, or swallow it.

Answer (score 0):

I think developers also try to consider the importance of "doing the right thing" in a particular context.  Often times for throw away code or when propagating the exception upwards wouldn't buy anything because the exception is fatal, you might as well save time and effort by "doing the wrong thing".

Answer (score 0):

From experience, Swallowing an exception is harmful mostly when it's not printed.  It helps to bring attention if you crash, and I'll do that deliberately at times, but simply printing the exception and continuing allows you to find the problem and fix it, and yet usually doesn't negatively effect others working on the same codebase.

I'm actually into Fail-Fast/Fail-HARD, but at least print it out.  If you actually "Eat" an exception (which is to truly do nothing: {}) It will cost someone DAYS to find it.

The problem is that Java forces you to catch a lot of stuff that the developer knows won't be thrown, or doesn't care if they are.  The most common is Thread.sleep().  I realize there are holes that might allow threading issues here, but generally you know that you are not interrupting it.  Period.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons why one would use catch Exception. In many cases it is a bad idea because you also catch RuntimeExceptions - and well you don't know in what state the underlying objects will be after this happens ? That is always the difficult thing with unexpected conditions: can you trust that the rest of the code will not fail afterwards.

Your example prints the stacktrace so at least your will know what the root cause might have been. In bigger software projects it is a better idea to log these things. And lets hope that the log component does not throw exceptions either our you might end up in an infinite loop (which will probably kill your JVM).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a checked exception and you don't want to handle it in a method, you should just have the method throw the exception.  Only catch and handle exceptions if you are going to do something useful with it. Just logging it is not very useful in my book as users rarely have time to be reading logs looking for exceptions or know what to do if an exception is thrown.

While wrapping the exception is an option, I would not suggest you do this unless; you are throwing a different exception to match an exist interface or there really is no way such an exception should be thrown.

BTW: If you want to re throw a checked exception you can do this with

```
try {
   // do something
} catch (Throwable e) {
   // do something with the exception
   Thread.currentThread().stop(e); // doesn't actually stop the current thread, but throws the exception/error/throwable
}
```

Note: if you do this, you should make sure the throws declaration for the method is correct as the compiler is unable to do this for you in this situation.

Comment: Just FTR: `Thread#stop()` has been deprecated and disabled in the meantime (it throws `UnsupportedOperationException`).

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a situation that, you have 2 mln rows to process. Each row has 10 columns. You know that the only 10 rows have a char in some column which this char is incorrect and not important and applies to the non-processing items next steps. Do you check all rows for each column in order to search for this char? Wrap the silent method is less costly. Of course, you have different approaches to served this situation. But one of them is a silent method.

Answer (score -2):

because it is a best practice. I thought everybody knew.
but the cold truth is that nobody really understands how to work with exceptions. The C error handing style made so much more sense.

Comment: Just because a large number of developers don't grok exceptions does not make "error return" better.  The C way of handling errors was and still is a horrendously error-prone (pun intended) mechanism.  Swallowing exceptions (which this example does, just not silently) is akin to calling a function in C without checking the return value.  The end-result is the same - the program "blunders" on.  This example is just a case of making Java error handling as bad C.