# Is IllegalStateException appropriate for an immutable object?

Tags: java, exception

Would you throw an `IllegalStateException` if:

1. A method is unable to do its job because of the value(s) of one or more fields
2. Those fields are `final` and assigned only in the constructor?

Textbook example: your class is an immutable `Collection<BigInteger>` and your method is supposed to return the maximum element, but this instance is empty.

I have read [Kevin Bourillon`s blog post](http://smallwig.blogspot.com/2008/06/common-java-unchecked-exception-types.html) on the subject and I am not sure which rule applies.

> UnsupportedOperationException - this means that the method invoked will always fail for an instance of this class (concrete type), regardless of how the instance was constructed.

Definitely not.  Many instances of this class are not empty and the operation would have succeeded.

> IllegalStateException - ... there does exist at least one alternate state that the instance in question could have been in, which would have passed the check ... <snip> ... Note also that this exception is appropriate whether or not it is possible to actually mutate this aspect of the instance's state, or it's already too late.

Not quite.  This instance was constructed with zero length, so *this instance* is not and could never have been non-empty.

> IllegalArgumentException - throwing this exception implies that there exists at least one other value for this parameter that would have caused the check in question to pass.

Might apply if the parameter in question is the implicit `this` parameter.  This is the exception I am tempted to throw, but I am concerned that it could be confusing.

---

**Update**: changed example from `Collection<Integer>` to `Collection<BigInteger>` because the fact that there was an identity element (`Integer.MIN_VALUE`) distracts from the question.

Comment: There are two different things in this question. **One** is to have an utility method, that returns the maximum of a given collection ( which as Jon points, is just like Collections.max method )  The **other** is in your question title, an *immutable object* having a max method, returning either, the max value of a delegated object, or the from himself. This second scenario is the one I'm answering http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267958/is-illegalstateexception-appropriate-for-an-immutable-object/3268353#3268353

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `IllegalStateException` is appropriate here.  The instance could have been in the correct state, if it was constructed correctly (i.e. the "it's already too late" part).

Comment: In that case it should be illegal argument exception but **when** you realize the object is being constructed incorrectly.

Comment: @OscarRyz That is only true if none of its methods could handle the given state. If getMax() is the only function for which the state is illegal, I would say IllegalStateException is appropriate.

Comment: ILM Mhh yeap, you're right about it, but I that case I would rather use `UnsupportedOperationException` but that's tricky ..mmmhh what about.. `UnsopporteOperationCausedByIllegalStateOriginatedByIllegalArgumentException` :)

Answer (score 11):

It doesn't sound like any of the common exception classes you mention above fit into the Textbook example.

You should throw a [`NoSuchElementException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) as that's exactly what the [`Collections.max()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-) method does.

Comment: I don't generally like using exception values like `-1` but in this case there *is* an identity element: `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.  That just shows I picked a bad example, so I'm going to edit the question to refer to `BigInteger` instead of `Integer` :-)

Comment: +1 to NoSuchElementException, but the `return -1` is a bad idea.  So is returning `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, which if returned would still not tell you whether there actually WAS a maximum value or not (what about a Collection containing only Integer.MIN_VALUE?  Null is a better choice than both but not as good as an exception IMO.

Comment: By the way, `NoSuchElementException` is what `Iterator.next()` throws too, if you go past the end.  They're conceptually similar: *there's nothing I could give you to satisfy your request.*

Comment: Arrgghh! Return -1 for a method supposed to return a maximum value? Arrgghhhh!

Comment: +1 Collections.max, throws that, because he can't control the arguments used to create immutable object, better would be IllegalArgumentException upon object creation. This is exactly the case finnw is describing

Comment: @MarkPeters: How about having the method `maxIfAbove(BigInteger defaultValue);` which returns the largest item if any is above `defaultValue`, or else returns `defaultValue`; if `defaultValue` is null, return the largest item if any exists, or else return `defaultValue` [i.e. null].

Comment: @Jon I've substantially altered your answer (which is explicitly against SO rules). The reason for this is that your answer consisted of *two* answers: `return -1` and `throw NoSuchElementException`. Please post a separate answer for `return -1` so the up- and downvotes can separate the bad from the good.

Answer (score 3):

If the state of the class is valid (empty collection), the max element is just null. If the state is not valid, an IllegalArgumentException should have been thrown at construction time.

Answer (score 3):

IllegalStateException comes closest to what you want: "this exception is appropriate whether or not it is possible to actually mutate this aspect of the instance's state".

Not UnsupportedOperationException, since it might succeed for some instance of that class, and throwing IllegalArgumentException for a method that (presumably) takes no arguments will certainly confuse people.

Comment: But an immutable object has only one state... :-/

Comment: No, it has only one ACCESSIBLE state. See the second cause of my first sentence.

Answer (score 2):

> *Is IllegalStateException appropriate for an immutable object?*

No, because immutable objects only have one state, and could not have pased from one legal state to another.

So, you're constructing an immutable object, and your object should have a max method

```
class YourObject {
    public BigInteger max(){ ... }
}
```

I this case `IllegalAgumentException` should be the correct, but not until the method is executed, but **when the object is created!**

So, in this scenario, if you have an immutable collection of bigintegers, and you create it with zero elements you are receiving an "invalid argument" upon the collection creation, that's when you have to throw the exception.

I agree with Jon, if your use case, or in you analysis, you're willing to support the rest of the operations, you could throw `NoSuchElementException`, but I think that would be to postpone the problem. Better would be to avoid the object creation in first place.

So, throwing IllegalArgumentException would be like:

```
  // this is my immutable object class
  final class YourObject {
      private final Collection<BigInteger> c;
      public YourObject( BigInteger ... values ) {
          if( values.length == 0 ) { 
              throw new IllegalAgumentException("Must specify at least one value");
          }
          ... initialize the rest... 
      }
      public BigInteger max() {
          // find and return the max will always work 
      }
   }
```

Client:

```
   YourObject o  = new YourObject(); // throws IllegalArgumentException 
   // the rest is not executed....
   doSomething( o ) ; 
   ...
   doSomething( YourObject o ) {
        BigInteger maximum = o.max();
   }
```

In this case you don't need to check for anything in `doSomething` because the program would fail at the instance creation, which in turn would be fixed at development time.

Throwing `NoSuchElementException`  would be like:

```
  final class YourObject {
      private final Collection<BigInteger> c;
      public YourObject( BigInteger ... values ) {
           // not validating the input  :-/ oh oh.. 
          ... initialize the rest... 
      }
      public BigInteger max() {
          if( c.isEmpty() ) { throw NoSuchElementException(); }
          // find and return the max will always work after this line
      }
   }
```

Client:

```
   YourObject o  = new YourObject(); // it says nothing
   doSomething( o ) ;
   ...
   doSomething( YourObject o ) {
        BigInteger maximum = o.max();// ooops!, why? what?...  
        // your object client will start questioning what did I do wrong
        // and chais of if( o != null && o.isEmpty() || moonPhaseIs... ) 
   }
```

Bear in mind, that, if a program is to fail, the best thing you can do is [to making it fail fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921471/why-java-people-frequently-consume-exception-silently/921583#921583).

[Collections.max](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29) have a different purpose, because being an utility method (not an immutable object ), he cannot held responsibility for the empty collection creation ( he wasn't present when that happened ), the only thing he can do is to say *"There is no such a thing as max in this collection"*  hence NoSuchElementException.

One last remark, RuntimeExceptions, [should be used for programming mistakes only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462501/exception-other-than-runtimeexception/462745#462745) ( those that can be fixed by testing the application before releasing it )

Answer (score 2):

You should thrown an `UnsupportedOpertationException` because that's what the Java Standard Library does in the same circumstance. Your example is a *type qualifier object protocol*. This pattern was defined in ["An Empirical Study of Object Protocols in the Wild"](http://www.nelsbeckman.com/nbeckman-empirical-ecoop2011.pdf):

> Some types disable certain methods for the lifetime of
>   the object. In the type qualiﬁer category, an object instance will enter an abstract state S at construction-time which it will never leave. Calls to an instance
>   method m, if it is disabled in state S will always fail.

In your example, your object enters an abstract state which I'll call *EmptyCollection* at construction time and it never leaves that state because the collection field is `final`. In the *EmptyCollection* abstract state all calls to the `getMax()` instance method will always fail.

Beckman studied open source Java programs looking for object protocols and categorized the resulting classes. The third most common protocol category, appearing in 16.4% of the protocols sampled, was *type qualifier*.

Beckman's paper lists many type qualifier examples and I selected three of them and in each case the unavailable method throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`:

1. When you create an unmodifiable list by calling `Colections.unmodifiableList(...)` and then call the `add` method on the resulting list.
2. When you create a `java.nio.ByteBuffer` that is not backed by an array and then call the `array` method.
3. When you create a `java.imageio.ImageWriteParam` that does not support compression and then call the `setCompressionMode` method.

Notice that these examples do *not* follow Kevin Bourillon's advice that you cite. The failure of these methods is dependent on how the instances were constructed. In examples 1 and 2 the instances that succeed and fail may be of different concrete classes since `List` and `ByteBuffer` are abstract. However, `ImageWriteParam` is a concrete class so one instance of `ImageWriteParam` may throw the `UnsupportedOperationException` while another one may not. Since the Java Standard Library designers also defined the exception types I would follow their lead instead of Mr. Bourillon's.

P.S. You should use `IllegalStateException` when instead the abstract state of your object *can change at runtime*. The other 83.6% of the examples in Beckman's paper are of this type.