# Android Database - No such table error

Tags: android, sql, httprequest

I am trying to use and a few http requests to populate a few tables in a database for and android application. When those tables are populated the part of the data from the tables will populate and expanded view. The problem is I am getting an error telling me that the table I am trying to create is not created.

Error Log:

```
01-05 13:33:29.811: E/SQLiteLog(1823): (1) no such table: lvl2List

01-05 13:33:29.831: E/AndroidRuntime(1823): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: lvl2List (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT id, Title, Description FROM lvl2List
```

Here is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private List<lvItem> myLVItems = new ArrayList<lvItem>();
    private List<Parent> myParent = new ArrayList<Parent>();
    ExpandableListView exv;
    final DBHelper db2 = new DBHelper(this);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        exv=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db2.open();

        lvl3 lvl3Item = new lvl3();
        lvl3Item.popDB(db2, myParent);
    }
}
```

**DBHelper.java**

```
public class DBHelper 
{
    private static final String Database_Name = "MyDBs";
    private static final int Database_Version = 2;

    public static final String Key_ID = "id";
    public static final String Key_Title = "Title";
    public static final String Key_Summary = "Summary";
    public static final String Key_Book = "Book";
    public static final String Key_Chapter = "Chapter";
    public static final String Key_Description = "Description";
    public static final String Key_SourceType = "SourceType";

    private static final String Lvl3_Table_Name = "lvl3";
    private static final String Lvl2_Table_Name = "lvl2List";
    private static final String Lvl1_Table_Name = "lvl1List";

    private static final String Lvl3_Create = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lvl3 (id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        +"Summary VARCHAR, Book VARCHAR, Chapter VARCHAR, Description VARCHAR, SourceType VARCHAR);";
    private static final String Lvl2_Create = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lvl2List (id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        +"Title VARCHAR, Description VARCHAR);";
    private static final String Lvl1_Create = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lvl1List (id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        +"Title VARCHAR, Description VARCHAR);";

    public DBHelper(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBhelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, Database_Name, null, Database_Version);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            try
            {
                db.execSQL(Lvl3_Create);
                db.execSQL(Lvl2_Create);
                db.execSQL(Lvl1_Create);
            }catch(SQLException e){

            }

        }

        public long insertLvl2Record(String Title, String Description)
        {
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(Key_Title, Title); 
            initialValues.put(Key_Description, Description); 

            return db.insert(Lvl2_Table_Name, null, initialValues);
        }

        public long insertLvl3Record(String Summary, String Book, String Chapter, String Description, String SourceType)
        {
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(Key_Summary, Summary); 
            initialValues.put(Key_Book, Book); 
            initialValues.put(Key_Chapter, Chapter); 
            initialValues.put(Key_Description, Description); 
            initialValues.put(Key_SourceType, SourceType); 

            return db.insert(Lvl3_Table_Name, null, initialValues);
        }

        public int getLvl2Count()
        {
            Cursor c = db.query(Lvl2_Table_Name, new String[] {Key_ID, Key_Title,Key_Description}, 
            null, null, null, null, null);

            return c.getCount();
        }

        public int getLvl3Count()
        {
            Cursor c = db.query(Lvl3_Table_Name, new String[] {Key_ID, Key_Summary,Key_Book,Key_Verse,Key_Scripts,Key_Description,Key_SourceType}, null, null, null, null, null);

            return c.getCount();
        }
```

**lvl3.java**

```
public class lvl3
{
    DBHelper db2;
    List<Parent> parent;
    public void popDB(DBHelper db, List<Parent> myParent) 
    {
        this.db2 = db;
        this.parent = myParent;
        Lvl3Thread lvl3theard = new Lvl3Thread();
        lvl3theard.execute();
    }
    public class Lvl3Thread extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
        {
            //Httprequest that get the data for the database… this works
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            lvl2 lvl2Item = new lvl2();
            lvl2Item.popDB(db2, parent);
        }
    }
}
```

**lvl2.java**

```
public class lvl3
{
    DBHelper db2;
    List<Parent> parent;
    public void popDB(DBHelper db, List<Parent> myParent) 
    {
        this.db2 = db;
        this.parent = myParent;
        Lvl3Thread lvl3theard = new Lvl3Thread();
        lvl3theard.execute();
    }
    public class Lvl3Thread extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
        {
            //Httprequest that get the data for the database… this works
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            lvl2 lvl2Item = new lvl2();
            lvl2Item.popDB(db2, parent);
        }
    }
    public void popLvl2List(DBHelper db)
    {
        List<lvItem> childlvItems = new ArrayList<lvItem>();
        Cursor cLvl3 = db.getAllLvl3Records();
        db.getLvl2Count(); //This is where the error is coming from stating that there is no lvl2List table
    }
}
```

I have tried using `db2.detLvl2Count();`  but that does not work. If I comment that line `out the program will run. I have tried reordering  the`db.execSQL`so that db.execSQL(Lvl2_Create);` is first, but I still get the error that the table does not exist.

Comment: why are you using `Key_ID, Key_Title,Key_Description` the column names are id, Title and Description.

Comment: What underlying database are you using?  Typically, `varchar` as a type requires a maximum length (something like `varchar(255)`).

Comment: @RohanKandwal I edited DBHelper.java to clarify Key_ID, Key_Title, Key_Description... Thank you

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm using an SQLiteDatabase. All the VarChar will be under 255

Comment: @user908759 `onCreate` of your `DBHelper` class will only be called the first time you open the app and the class is called. Did you by any chance add the `lvl2List` table later on? If so, then try to re-install the app and try again. 
When adding/changing SQL tables, use the `onUpgrade` method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase, int, int)
Also in your `onCreate` method of `DBHelper` you're "eating" the `SQLException` - don't do this - it might have interesting info for you ;-)

Comment: @Darwind Thank you! that worked, please post this in the Answer section so I can give you credit. Also can you explain a little more on what you mean by "eating" the SQLException, or post a link.

Comment: @user908759 any time :-) I've added an answer together with a bit more about exception handling, even though it's a bit off topic in this case :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onCreate` of your `DBHelper` class will only be called the first time you open the app and the class is called.

Did you by any chance add the `lvl2List` table later on?

If so, then try to re-install the app and try again.

When adding/changing SQL tables, use the `onUpgrade` method. See the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29)

Also in your `onCreate` method of `DBHelper` you're "eating" the `SQLException` - don't do this - it might have interesting info for you ;-)

By eating the `Exception` I mean, that you "silently" handle the exception and move on.

This is your `onCreate` method of the `DatabaseHelper`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
        db.execSQL(Lvl3_Create);
        db.execSQL(Lvl2_Create);
        db.execSQL(Lvl1_Create);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // Handle a possible exception here.
    }
}
```

Notice the `catch`-clause. Here you should at least do `e.printStacktrace();` or `Log.e(e);`.

In your case you might not have gotten anything out this logging, because the `onCreate` method was only called the first time you installed and started the app.

See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921471/why-java-people-frequently-consume-exception-silently) about the issue or just search on [Google](https://www.google.dk/search?q=java%20eating%20exceptions&oq=java%20eating%20exceptions&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3828j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8) - this is a known "issue" / "behaviour" we as programmers tend to do ;-)

A good trail about how to handle exceptions, can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Answer (score 0):

I know this topic is old and solved. But I would like to include this tip for other people like me having the same problem. Try to include .db in the file name like:

```
    private static final String Database_Name = "MyDBs.db";
```

This solved the problem for me