# while & do-while loop with users decision to run program again

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I have a problem with my restaurant assignment - I'm required to

1. Create a while loop with a required quantity that user purchases to be between 1 and 15. User has 3 attempts and if after the third time he doesn't put the right quantity 1
2. Using a do- while loop user has to answer if he wants to run a program again. If he answers 'Y' (for yes) it runs again, if the answer is 'N' (for no ) it terminates.

I keep getting errors: the while loop does only 2 attempts, and the do while doesn't work at all.

```
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class newone {
       public static void main (String[] args){
         char repeat;             
         // To hold 'y' or 'n'      
         String input;      

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");
        //to use: df.format(doubleVariable)

        //Display any welcome message at the top of the output screen
        System.out.println("Welcome!");

        double price = 5.0;
        System.out.println("Burger is " + df.format(price));

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

            int attempts = 0;
            int maxAttempts = 3;
            int quantity;

            System.out.print("Enter amount of burgers: ");

            quantity = keyboard.nextInt();
        //LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO 3... 
        while(quantity <1 || quantity >=15 && attempts<=maxAttempts){

            if(quantity < 1 || quantity >= 15){

                System.out.println("That is an invalid amount, please try  again");
                    quantity= keyboard.nextInt();
                    ++attempts;
                    }
                    else if(quantity>1 && quantity<15){

                //user entered a valid amount  
                System.out.println("The amount is valid. You ordered: "+ quantity);
                double subTotal = quantity * price;
            }

            while (attempts>=maxAttempts){
                System.out.println("Too many attempts, you can't order");
                break;
                }
            }

         do{ 
     System.out.println("Would you like to run the program again?");        
     System.out.print("Enter Y for yes or N for no: "); 
     input = keyboard.nextLine();    // Read a line.     
     repeat = input.charAt(0);       // Get the first char.   
     } 
//it gives me an error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)

     while (repeat == 'Y' || repeat == 'y'); 



            }
        }}
```

Comment: Put `System.out.println("String length" + input.length());` after your `input = keyboard.nextLine();`.

Answer (score 0):

Below line causes the error:

`repeat = input.charAt(0);`

Perhaps user is not providing any inputs (i.e. user just hits enter when program asks for any input) and hence, `string` doesn't have any character. Extracting first character from blank string throws this error.

The solution will be to check for empty string (using `length()` method) before executing `charAt(0)`.

Answer (score -2):

You have lots of problems here.

Here's how I'd do it.  It's never too early to learn about decomposition and writing clean, readable code:

```
/**
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 3/4/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35806509/java-while-do-while-loop-with-users-decision-to-run-program-again/35806638?noredirect=1#comment59284245_35806638
 */

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BurgerKing {

    public static final int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 3;
    public static final int MIN_QUANTITY = 1;
    public static final int MAX_QUANTITY = 15;
    public static final NumberFormat PRICE_FORMAT = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    public static void main (String[] args){

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer;
        do {
            System.out.println("Welcome!  Please place your order");
            int quantity = getBurgerQuantity(keyboard);
            double price = getBurgerPrice(keyboard);
            System.out.println(String.format("Your total is: %s", PRICE_FORMAT.format(quantity*price)));
            System.out.print("Another order? [Y/N]: ");
            answer = keyboard.nextLine();
        } while ("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(answer));
    }

    public static boolean isValidQuantity(int quantity) {
        return (quantity >= MIN_QUANTITY && quantity =< MAX_QUANTITY);
    }

    public static int getBurgerQuantity(Scanner scanner) {
        int numBurgers;
        int attempts = 0;
        do {
            System.out.print("How many burgers would you like? ");
            numBurgers = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        } while (!isValidQuantity(numBurgers) && (++attempts < MAX_ATTEMPTS));
        if (attempts == MAX_ATTEMPTS) throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("%d attempts is too many", attempts));
        return numBurgers;
    }

    public static double getBurgerPrice(Scanner scanner) {
        String price;
        System.out.print("Name your burger price: ");
        price = scanner.nextLine();
        return Double.parseDouble(price);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help! After trying the code out it still gives me the message : Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException and does not start it again.

Comment: The code that I posted is a self contained, running application.  Yours will have to change.   Try taking out that charAt call and simply compare the string you get in the input.  My code works.

Comment: -1 Josh Bloch (and many other people, me included) strongly advocate against introducing user-defined marker exception types for handling exceptions that are essentially non-custom in their behaviour. In this case, your `TooManyAttemptsException` is just a code smell, making the code unnecessarily lengthy and complicated - it has little semantic value; doing a `throw new IllegalStateException(attempts + ` attempts is too many!`)` is a lot better solution in this case (also, why `String.format` instead of `+` in this particular case? it's neither faster nor more readable)

Comment: @duffymo related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27064/719662 , http://allenlsy.com/NOTES-of-Effective-Java-8-Exceptions/#60.-favor-the-use-of-standard-exceptions

Comment: Fair enough, thank you.  Why String format?  I appreciate the formatting when I want it.

Comment: is concatenating Strings really a formatting action? I wouldn't say so; if you'd, for example, require a custom formatting on the number - I'd agree on using `format`; yet simple `number + " " + someString` is the exact use case of `+` String operator, not format itself. As a side note: IMO it should be `IllegalStateException` rather thatn `IllegalArgumentException`, since the amount of attempts is a function state, not an argument.